# Problem with Create new HTML Attribute in Tag Name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add  attribute `class='notranslate'` in `<pre>` to prevent Google Translating  content in `<pre>` tag.

I use this JavaScript, and it work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName("PRE")[0];
var att = document.createAttribute("class");
att.value = "notranslate";
pre.setAttributeNode(att);
//]]>
</script>
```

But there is problem. That's JavaScript only work at first `<pre>` tag.

Anyone can help me, how to Add `class='notranslate'` in entire tag `<pre>` ?

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: `var pre` is a list of nodes. Loop through them and set your attribute to all if them.

Comment: Using jQuery: `$('pre').addClass("notranslate");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use forEach to iterate over the values of the object which is returned by the getElementsByTagName and create and append attributes in the loop

```js
var pre = document.getElementsByTagName("PRE");

Object.values(pre).forEach((x)=>{
var att = document.createAttribute("class");
att.value = "notranslate";
x.setAttributeNode(att);
})
```

```html
<pre>a</pre><pre>b</pre><pre>c</pre>
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dont do `document.getElementsByTagName("PRE")[0];` which gives you the first element (thats what the`[0]` is for) but use a loop.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("PRE").forEach(pre => {
  const att = document.createAttribute("class");
  att.value = "notranslate";
  pre.setAttributeNode(att);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It only works at the first pre tag because you are selecting the first element of the returned array.

Try

```
for (let pre of document.getElementsByTagName('pre')) {
    // ... your manipulation code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only the first element by adding `[0]`. You need to iterate over the entire NodeList

You can also use the `classList.add` to prevent clobbering of existing classes

```js
Object.values(document.getElementsByTagName('pre'))
    .forEach(pre => pre.classList.add('notranslate'))
```